# handle retrofit error as a gson model

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit2, gson

i have a web service for registration. and i have a success response for response code 200 like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "email": "azadbar@yahoo.com"
    },
    "code": 201,
    "success": true
}
```

and i have error response with code 422 like this

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

but when also i have problem with password the response error show me like this

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email must be a valid email address."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password must be at least 6 characters.",
            "The password confirmation does not match."
        ]
    }
}
```

the problem is some field some time show and some time is gone. and also we have some response model and in retrofit interface we should only have One response like RegisterResponse in below sample

```
@POST("/api/v1/register")
Call<RegisterResponse> register(@Body RegisterRequest request);
```

how can i handle this response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **pojo that means a model class of name RegisterResponse** that will have the properties that you are getting in your JSON response. So, according to your example case, it would be like :

```
Class RegisterResponse{
   private Data data;
   private String code;
   private Boolean success;
   private String  message;
   private Error errors;
}

Class Data{
  private String email;  
}

Class Error{
  private List<String> email;
  private List<String> password;
}
```

Now inside every class, you need to create the getter and setter for every properties that you have included.
So when the response comes then handle it accordingly that mean if it comes null, set the property to null else set the received value for the respective property

Comment: remember. the response bode is null when error code is not 200

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a model with all possible fields and depending on result some will be filled or null.

```
class Model{
    private Data data; 
    private int code; 
    private boolean success;
    private Errors errors;
    private String message;

    public isSuccess(){
        return success;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: remember. the response bode is null when error code is not 200